# Image gets mixed up after orientation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm currently working on an app which is like a photo gallery. It supports orientations too. The `UIImageView` which contains the `UIImage`, is in `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`. When I change the orientation of the device, some part of the `UIImage` gets displayed on the part of the view which is not a part of the aspect fit region.Any ideas to tackle it??

Comment: Check that the frame of the UIImageView isn't being resized incorrectly on orientation change.

Comment: @GuyKogus: It's been resized correctly. I have verified it using breakpoints. One more thing to tell here is, the image UIImageView is in top of a UIScrollView.

Comment: If you are using SDWebImage to load your image content, it gives a default contentMode.

Comment: When I have an issue with borders I often set the borderColor and borderWidth of the view's layer. That will let me know exactly what's happening with the view's content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got similar kind of problem while using zooming effect. After changing the orientation of device while the image is zoomed in, it overlaps the imageView. Try to zoom out the image just after changing the orientation. That worked for me.